# installing react-native always failed using Mac Terminal

Tags: node.js, git, bash, macos

When installing react native using npm and run ,I always  encounter react-native: command not found . Even I uninstall npm and install npm again and run ...still failed. Would you please tell me what to do ?

Here is my log:

```
Last login: Wed Aug 23 13:26:19 on console
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/larrylo/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/larrylo/package.json'
npm WARN larrylo No description
npm WARN larrylo No repository field.
npm WARN larrylo No README data
npm WARN larrylo No license field.

up to date in 0.153s
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ node -v
v8.4.0
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ npm -v
5.3.0
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ npm install npm@latest -g
/Users/larrylo/.npm-packages/bin/bin/npm -> /Users/larrylo/.npm-packages/bin/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/Users/larrylo/.npm-packages/bin/bin/npx -> /Users/larrylo/.npm-packages/bin/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@5.3.0
updated 1 package in 12.376s
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/react-native.git
Cloning into 'react-native'...
remote: Counting objects: 153309, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (102/102), done.
Receiving objects:  29% (44537/153309), 59.25 MiB | 107.00 KiB/s    

remote: Total 153309 (delta 86), reused 51 (delta 44), pack-reused 153163
Receiving objects: 100% (153309/153309), 137.87 MiB | 114.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (107173/107173), done.
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ 
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ 
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ react-native init AwesomeProject
-bash: react-native: command not found
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ npm install -g react-native-cli

npm WARN gentlyRm not removing /Users/larrylo/.npm-packages/bin/bin/react-native as it wasn't installed by /Users/larrylo/.npm-packages/bin/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
/Users/larrylo/.npm-packages/bin/bin/react-native -> /Users/larrylo/.npm-packages/bin/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
+ react-native-cli@2.0.1
updated 1 package in 8.92s
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ 
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$ react-native init AwesomeProject
-bash: react-native: command not found
Larrys-MacBook-Pro:~ larrylo$
```

Every time I run Terminal , I have to install react-native-cli and go `export PATH=/Users/larrylo/.npm-packages/bin/bin:$PATH`

again. That is absolutely tedious!

Comment: Add the export PATH line into your `.bash_profile`

Comment: Lohit Gupta : please tell me how to

how to ?

Comment: Did you install Node.js through Homebrew?

Comment: I have done that.